# Setting IPrincipal in Message handler or Filter does not go into controller correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, basic-authentication, asp.net-authorization

I have a Web API 2 project and we are using basic authorization.  The client sends the username:password in the authorization header - we extract it and connect to an LDAP server to

1. verify the user
2. verify their password, and then
3. get an attribute value from their LDAP response and pass it into the
   IPrincipal of the request.

The issue is, when I access the **IPrincipal** in the controller via **System.Web.Http.ApiController.User.Identity.Name** I am seeing that the value passed in is not always correct!

**Example**:
In either a message handler or a filter, I set the IPrincipal as so:

```
    public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {

        ...other code...

        private IPrincipal ReturnPrincipal(string UserID, List<string> roles)
        {
            roles.Add("SomeRole");

            // UserID = 7144 or 8899 (load testing)
            var identity = new GenericIdentity(UserID, "Basic");
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles.ToArray());

            return principal;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Here is how we are setting the principal in the filter:

```
        var principal = await AuthenticateAsync(UserID, password, cancellationToken);

        if (principal == null)
        {
            // Authentication was attempted but failed. Set ErrorResult to indicate an error.
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid username or password", request);
        }
        else
        {
            // Authentication was attempted and succeeded. Set Principal to the authenticated user.
            context.Principal = principal;
        }
```

Later in the lifecycle of the request, in the controller, I try to access this value like so:

```
    protected bool IsAuthorized(string UserID)
    {
        return User.Identity.Name == UserID;
    }
```

So what happens here is I'm getting the **User.Identity.Name** from **ApiController.User.Identity.Name**, under **load testing**, I send 2 threaded parallel requests at the SAME TIME - when I do this, the Request object shows the correct ID in the URL, however, the IPrincipal that is set in the filter is NOT right.  This is a fixed test with expected results, so this should never happen.  If it stagger the calls, the issue does not come up!  If the calls are sent at the same time, the issue occurs 100% of the time.

Here is how I am calling the service:

```
            var task1 = Task.Run(() => CallServerInParallel(requests2, api));
            var task2 = Task.Run(() => CallServerInParallel2(requests2, api));

            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

...

```
    private static void CallServerInParallel2(List<int> requests2, string api)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(requests2, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, async p =>
        {
            var client = new RemoteClient(api);
            client.AddAuthHeader("d2JsMTE4NTgzOUBbdGVhY2NlcHQuY29tOnRlc3QxMjM0");
            var response = await client.Get<dynamic>("CustomerSite/5537");
        });
    }

    private static void CallServerInParallel2(List<int> requests2, string api)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(requests2, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, async p =>
        {
            var client = new RemoteClient(api);
            client.AddAuthHeader("d2JsMTE4NTgzOUBkdGVhY1NlcHQuY29tOnRlc3QxMjM0");
            var response = await client.Get<dynamic>("CustomerSite/5538");
        });
    }
```

**How can I access the correct IPrincipal.User.Identity.Name for the request?**

Comment: How is `ReturnPrincipal` getting called?  Where are you actually setting the principal on the context?

Comment: Adding to the thread above since its a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

As referenced here : [Setting the Principal](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

I got around this kind of issue by making sure that in my filter after setting the context principal that I also do the following

> If your application performs any custom authentication logic, you must
>   set the principal on two places:
>
> - **Thread.CurrentPrincipal**. This property is the standard way to set the thread's principal in .NET.
> - **HttpContext.Current.User**. This property is specific to ASP.NET.
>
> The following code shows how to set the principal:

```
private void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
{
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
}
```

> For web-hosting, you must set the principal in both places; otherwise
>   the security context may become inconsistent. For self-hosting,
>   however, HttpContext.Current is null. To ensure your code is
>   host-agnostic, therefore, check for null before assigning to
>   HttpContext.Current, as shown.

```
var principal = await AuthenticateAsync(UserID, password, cancellationToken);

if (principal == null) {
    // Authentication was attempted but failed. Set ErrorResult to indicate an error.
    context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid username or password", request);
} else {
    // Authentication was attempted and succeeded. Set Principal to the authenticated user.
    context.Principal = principal;
    SetPrincipal(principal);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the solution.  I tested it just now, and it did not fix the issue. :(